# How to add gzipping to ASP.NET WebApi Fileserver?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, gzip

I have an asp.net web api application which has to serve files. To do that I'm using build-in file server like this:

```
            appBuilder.UseFileServer(fileServerOptions);
```

How do enable gzipping for files that are served through this file server?

I've tried to use package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression.Compressor and to apply it with the following code:

```
            config.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new ServerCompressionHandler(new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));
```

But it didn't help :(

Thanks in advance!